# How to fix bug on validation 'min' Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5

I am trying to validate an integer field using a **FormRequest** class extension.
The validation works fine in most cases but i found an issue.

The rule is

```
'operation_id'      => 'required|integer|min:1'
```

It works with values like:

```
operation_id: 0  //false
operation_id: 0s //false
operation_id: -1 //false
operation_id: 1  //true
```

But It fails when setting value

```
operation_id: 0\n //It throws a true when it should be a false
```

I am using Laravel 5.8, and I am sending the data to test requests validation through Postman.

Comment: `0\n` is not an integer, so even if it passes `min` it should still fail at `integer`

Comment: yes, but it doesn't :(

Comment: is that a literal `'0\n'` or are you trying to say that is `"0\n"` ... 0 with a new line?

Comment: 0 with new line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Laravel's integer validation is simply using PHP's [`filter_var`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) function. ([Laravel Source](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/17830b2170361eb2b3b59837b33ef8605d2d6200/src/Illuminate/Validation/Concerns/ValidatesAttributes.php#L1086)).

Which for some reason will parse `"0\n"` (zero + new line) as a valid integer `0`.

```
// Example:

$var = "0\n"; // This get's parsed as zero + new line
$result = filter_var($var, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT); // true

$var = '0\n'; // This is string literal "0\n"
$result = filter_var($var, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT); // FALSE
```

So, it seems like the `integer` validation passes for the above reason and the `min` passes because the string length (3) is > the min (1).

Answer (score 0):

You can trim all the inputs before validation:

```
$request->merge(array_map("trim", $request->all()));
```

so the `trim` will remove all whitespace chars including newline from the string.

Comment: there is a `TrimStrings` middleware that should already be in place as a global middleware

Comment: If it was there there won't be a newline at the end of the input I guess, right?